# abstract classes ,constructor and interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I'm really confused, and I've read a TON of questions on this topic and I have not been able to pinpoint anything specifically that an interface can do that an abstract class cannot do.

Comment: There are lots of answers to questions like this. You'd be better of asking questions in already answered questions. Short answer, though: interfaces are implemented, not inherited. Java has no multiple inheritance but one can implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: @merryprankster - you can't ask a question on a question, only answer it. Low rep user's can't comment on existing questions/answers either.

Answer (score 9):

A class can implement multiple interfaces, but it cannot implement multiple abstract classes.

Comment: implement abstract class? Should it be extend..?

Answer (score 3):

Interface itself cannot do anything. It just defines kind of contract between the class(es) that provide some functionality and the caller.

Abstract class is the class that defined as `abstract`. If class has at least one abstract method (i.e. method without implementation) it must be defined as abstract. But abstract class can contain implementations as well.

Interface cannot contain implementation. Only abstract methods and constants (static final fields).

Class can implement several interfaces and extend only one class (including abstract class).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract class can also contain function implementation rather than just defining the functions that have to be implemented by inheriting classes

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes are partially implemented classes, that will be extended by concrete classes(non-abstract), to be implemented.

Example:
[image]

This example does not mean that the sub classes must implement those methods(as it happens when implementing an interface). You can declare a subclass abstract, and the implementation will be done later by annother sub-sub-class. (For example: Boat can have subclasses "SpeedBoat" and FisshingBoat, and the may implement honk() in different ways)

The interface are the eyes of class to the outside world. What classes can do is declared in the interface, but implemented in the class.

A class can implement many interfaces, but can extend only one class. 
See this little example of interfaces:

[image]

As you can see when we use interfaces we can have a lot of flexibility. Some Enemies can do things that some Heroes can do too(DarkKnight can throw arrows). 
I hope you now feel the difference between the abstract classes and interfaces.

Remember this about interfaces and Abstract classes:

- Interfaces dont have variables, just non implemented methods(abstract methods implicitly)
- Classes that implement interfaces must have all the methods of the interface in its body
- One class can extend only one class but implement more than one interface
- If a class has an abstract method, it must bee declared as abstract.
- Abstract classes can implement interfaces
- Interfaces can extend other interfaces(more than one)

I dont know if i forget something, i hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class can everything that a Interface can do. However inverse of this is not correct.

Comment: Not really, you're missing the point. Interface is like a contract. Abstract class is something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class can contain abstract methods, abstract property as well as other members (just like normal class).
Interface can only contain abstract methods, properties but we don’t need to put abstract and public keyword. All the methods and properties defined in Interface are by default public and abstract.
We can see abstract class contains private members also we can put some methods with implementation also. But in case of interface only methods and properties allowed

Answer (score 0):

Interface and abstract class almost both are same the major difference is using interface we are not able to define the body of the method but using abstract class we can define the body of the method inside the abstract class or while implementing it.
e.g

```
Interface abc()
{
 string xyz();
}

abstract abc()
{
 string xyz()
{
// define body
}
}
or 
abstract abc()
{
 string xyz();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is a class - it defines all or part of an implementation of some behaviour for a class of objects, but with some extension points for concrete subclasses to provide.

An interface is a type - it defines the set of operations which are provided by any class implementing the interface.

You're almost asking whether there is anything that a candidate can do that the job description can't. Creating an abstract class says 'here is a template for some implementation'. Creating an interface says 'I expect an object to provide these capabilities'. You can use virtual methods in an abstract class to implement some aspects of a type, but the intention is different.